# pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, database-backups, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

I am running ubuntu 14.04. while backing up a database on postgreSQL i am following error:

```
/usr/bin/pg_dump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password  --format custom --section pre-data --section data --section post-data --verbose --file "/home/naveen/consumerDB/CONSUMER_DB" "CONSUMER_DB"
pg_dump: server version: 9.4.8; pg_dump version: 9.3.17
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

Process returned exit code 1.
```

**Can anyone please help. I tried many other stack overflow links but nothing seems to be working.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message seems fairly clear. `pg_dump` for PostgreSQL 9.3 won't dump a PostgreSQL 9.4 database. Maybe you need to run `pg_dump` from PostgreSQL 9.4?

If you installed both from packages you'll be using `pg_wrapper` and should use Debian/Ubuntu's `update-alternatives` to change `pg_dump` to point to 9.4's `pg_dump`. Or run it via the direct path to the actual binary.

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL